# Reading a maven settings.xml when building with gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a maven settings.xml located in:

```
 /home/u123/.m2/settings.xml
```

where I specify a remote maven repository:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>my.repo</id>
               <url>http://myrepo/ </url>
          </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

In this repo I have deployed an artifact - actually its a gradle plugin.

Now I try to build another project that needs to use this plugin/artifact using the below build.gradle file:

```java
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.test:my-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

But the build fails:

```
...
> Could not find group:com.test, module:my-gradle-plugin, version:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
...
```

Gradle cannot find my-gradle-plugin even though I have the above settings.xml file pointing to the remote maven repository.

If I instead specify the repository *inside* my build.gradle file it works:

```java
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://myrepo/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.test:my-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

Based on this post:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/have_mavenlocal_check_m2_home_conf_settings_xml

it seems that gradle considers the settings.xml file so what is wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an open ticket related to this that will be hopefully implemented:

http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2365

But as a workaround you can use some groovy scripting in the build.gradle to achieve this. In my case I needed the authentication information from settings.xml. But this could easily be adapted to get repository info.

Example:

```groovy
def getMavenSettingsCredentials = {
    String userHome = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
    File mavenSettings = new File(userHome, ".m2/settings.xml")
    def xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
    def output = xmlSlurper.parse(mavenSettings)
    return output."servers"."server"
}

def getCredentials = {
    def entries = getMavenSettingsCredentials()
    for (entry in entries) {
        if ( entry."id".text() == "my-server" ) {
            return [username: entry.username.text(), password: entry.password.text()]
    }
  }
}
uploadArchives {
def creds = getCredentials()
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    configuration = configurations.deployerJars
    repository(url: "http://my-release-repository/releases/") {
        authentication(userName: creds["username"], password: creds["password"])
    }
    snapshotRepository(url: "http://my-snapshot-repository/snapshots/") {
        authentication(userName: creds["username"], password: creds["password"])
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and is helpful for general information as well (scripting in Gradle build file). I would also recommend anyone reading this to see @PeterKahn's answer below, which does not require extra scripting, but does require extra plugins.

Comment: 4 years lagert, the ticket isn't closed. I like your solution, unfortunately it seems like it doesn't use settings security

Answer (score 12):

[gradle-maven-settings-plugin](https://github.com/mark-vieira/gradle-maven-settings-plugin) works for me (at least in my Windows environment)

One should add

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'net.linguica.maven-settings' version '0.5'
}
```

to the `build.gradle` and then can add repository like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name = 'myRepo' // should match <id>myRepo</id> of appropriate <server> in Maven's settings.xml
        url = 'https://intranet.foo.org/repo'
    }
}
```

which will use `myRepo` credentials from the Maven's `settings.xml` to access the https://intranet.foo.org/repo repository

Comment: If your maven settings.xml is having auth details, then just adding "net.linguica.maven-settings" solves the problem

Answer (score 8):

You have to declare all repositories in your Gradle build script. `settings.xml` is only used to find the location of the local Maven repository, for example when resolving `repositories { mavenLocal() }`.

Answer (score 4):

I used maven-publish, maven-publish-auth plugins to accomplish this without parsing the settings by hand

[How can Gradle Use Repository Settings From Maven's Settings.xml to publish artifacts](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_can_gradle_use_repository_settings_from_mavens_settings_xml_to_publish_artifacts_to_a_repository?rfm=1)

Hope it is of use.

Peter

Comment: Haven't worked for me (may be because I run it under Windows and it expects that the default location of settings file is `~/.m2/settings.xml`)

Comment: I think this link is broken it is taking me to https://discuss.gradle.org/ no discussion on setting.xml

Answer (score 4):

See: https://github.com/ci-and-cd/maven-settings-decoder

I use it in gradle build script to avoid expose nexus password in build.gradle or environment variable.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    ...
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'cn.home1.tools:maven-settings-decoder:1.0.5.OSS'
  }
}
...
ext.mavenSettings = new cn.home1.tools.maven.SettingsDecoder();
ext.nexusSnapshotsUser = mavenSettings.getText("//server[id='${nexus}-snapshots']/username/text()")
ext.nexusSnapshotsPass = mavenSettings.getText("//server[id='${nexus}-snapshots']/password/text()")
println "${nexus}-snapshots username: " + mavenSettings.getText("//server[id='${nexus}-snapshots']/username/text()")
println "${nexus}-snapshots password: " + mavenSettings.getText("//server[id='${nexus}-snapshots']/password/text()")
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use mavenLocal() in your repositories section of build.gradle file. This should read ~/.m2/settings.xml file in your home directory.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: This didnt work for me, I had to explicitly copy the maven url into gradle build file.

Comment: I don't know who and why upvoted this answer as it doesn't work at all. `mavenLocal()` refers only to the maven repo and not the settings.xml file which is one folder above.

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the same error: `Could not find <dependency>.`