# Is there a way to reference maven settings.xml within gradle automatically?

Tags: maven, gradle

Within my maven settings.xml, there are lines such as:

```
<server>
  <id>releases</id>
  <username>myname</username>
  <password>mypassword</password>
</server>
```

And also, defined within the maven build:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
    <name>Local repo on Banana</name>
    <id>releases</id>
    <url>http://banana.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

---

Within gradle, you define a repository reference via:

```
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository (url: "http://banana.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases", id: "releases"){
            //...filler...
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The question is, can gradle reference the main settings.xml file on the system?** 
*(and therefore automatically pull the credentials that match the repository id, just like maven does)*

Thus far, the only way I could find to provide authentication credentials, is to explicitly list them within the gradle.build...like so:

```
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository (url: "http://banana.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases", id: "releases"){
            authentication(userName: "billybob", password: "bananas?!")
        }
    }
}
```

My current plan is to reference environment variables, but I was hoping that there was a way to reference the existing settings.xml definition(s).

Comment: Have you seen [Reading a maven settings.xml when building with gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522676/reading-a-maven-settings-xml-when-building-with-gradle)

Comment: Ideally you would migrate to `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` instead.

Comment: I have not seen that. I'll take a peak.

Comment: oh god that answer is ugly ;( .  I might just go the gradle.properties route...or have them both use environment variables on the machine...

Comment: The long term solution is that this: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2365 , gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the gradle.properties file:

```
repoUser=user123
repoPassword=123abc
```

Then in your build.gradle add the following:

```
repositories {
maven {
    credentials {
        username repoUser
        password repoPassword
    }
    url "http://nexus........."
}
```

}